# Book Search, 70's/80's young adult Sci-fi

Tags: story-identification

As is often the case, I can recall only some details about the book, not the main plot itself.

- There were several sets of children on Earth in the near future, separated from their parents for a long time.
- The parents had jobs in space/another planet.   The children wanted to see them.
- They built a ship - forged a purchase order or something for an asteroid what had been captured and was on earth, then more hacking/forging for laser time to hollow it out, outfit it, and so on.
- They went off and found their parents, but there was another threat and they had to leave.
- The parents' base(?) was isolated and armed with 10 laser weapons of some kind, called, I think "p.o.w's" which fired a targeting laser and would then fire if the targeting laser detected something.
- The children stole/were given three of them and attached them to the asteroid ship.
- They when went off and...that's all I remember.

This would have been read as a library book in the middle to late 80's.   I've a vague feeling it might have been a short series of possibly three books.   Equally likely to just have been one, though.

Been trying to remember what it was for a few years now.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: You've got literally all I can recall.   It was in the UK and at the earliest read in 84.   It would have been new, and probably newly published at that time.
No character names.   Mix of boys and girls.   Some siblings, some just friends as the parents were friends of one another.
Parents didn't mean to be gone for so long, but it was outside of their control.

Comment: The pow laser is a strong memory because of the idiotic name.   It might have been a different name, but it was a similar idea; TLA making a word, and an equally silly one.
Equally, it was more of a forget purchase order than a hack to buy the asteroid.
There was a "sad comment from a foreman that they weren't the first kids to think they'd had the bright idea of hollowing out an asteroid to go off and find their parents", but not too them directly.

Comment: The laser itself was described as a fairly featureless cylinder.   No details on power source, though I think it had to be connected to the ships power.   It was man portable, though.

Comment: Sounds like a gun for firing prisoners at your enemies....

Comment: The asteroid was "on earth"? Not in earth orbit?

Comment: It had been captured, and I have a feeling it was a metal asteriod that was then stored on earth.   It was then moved somewhere to work on.   Conceivably earth orbit, but it read more as some field or yard on Earth.

Comment: Might be [Starstormers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Fisk#Starstormers_Series) though I don't remember enough of the details to be sure.

Comment: That has potential.   Let me dig into it a bit.   Right now, I'm going to call it 70% chance of you being right.

Comment: Ok, looks like it, cover looks familiar:
http://www.peterelson.co.uk/gallery/image.php?cat=11&id=159
'space ship they build from junk parts including an asteroid, a drive, a space scoop and a lock and dock'.
Mark this one as solved.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Jim would like you to post that as the answer if you would. :)

Answer (score 3):

It does indeed look like Starstormers.   Author sounds right, details look good.   I'm not bothered enough to buy a copy to check for sure, but I'm confident it's right

Comment: Can you provide the details that match? And you can accept a self-answer 48 hours after asking the question.

Comment: I was trying to close it off after having received what I believe to be the correct answer.
The Author sounds Familiar.
The cover looks right - from the link found after being provided with the title.   I recall the cover matched the novels description well - the text that the ship was made from junk including an asteroid is correct.   
I'd prefer the commenter who suggested Starstormers 'answered' it, then I'd mark it correct.

Comment: better duplicate target at: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108502/looking-for-title-and-author-of-childrens-science-fiction-book-series-and-tv-sh