# Novel series where kids crew a snail shell shaped ship

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, childrens-novel

Very vague on the details. I would have read these books in the late 80s, possibly around '87-'88. They were in my school library, which had students from age 6 to 10, so would have been age appropriate.

You could also say the ship was shaped like a nautilus, I guess. I'm pretty sure there were diagrams of the ships layout in the cover.

There may have been a robot sidekick. I have an inkling of a mining/industrial element or aesthetic.

Comment: I've read this, I thought it was _Star Ka'at_ by Andre Norton but I think that I must have read them at the same time and have the wrong title.

Comment: Possibly related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108502/looking-for-title-and-author-of-childrens-science-fiction-book-series-and-tv-sh/108516 . (I wouldn't regard it as a duplicate, even though it may relate to the same series of books, as that question relates to the BBC adaptation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the *Starstormers* series, by David Higginbottom writing as [Nicholas Fisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Fisk). The ship, christened the *Starstormer*, was, IIRC, a hollowed-out meteorite, and there was indeed a robot involved though I don't recall any particular details of it.

There's a synopsis of the first book, Starstormers, [here](https://www.hachettechildrens.co.uk/Books/detail.page?isbn=9781444919486). I had, I think, the second book, in which the kids find their parents.

Comment: Startstormers was my immediate thought too, as soon as I read kids as crew, but I don't remember its shape being anything other than a hollowed-out rock.

Comment: Starstormers didn't mean anything to me. Nor David Higginbottom but as soon as you said Nicholas Fisk, I knew this was it. I might have made the snail shape up but I suspect a meteorite was involved when I mentioned the mining aesthetic! Thanks so much!